# Looking for doing a small animation with gnuplot and ffmpeg

Tags: bash, animation, ffmpeg, gnuplot

I am trying to do a small animations from multiples images (generated by the plot of input files test_matter_power_xxx.dat).

Here the script:

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in {1..398}; do
gnuplot -p <<-EOFMarker
set terminal jpeg;
set logscale x;
set title "Matter Abgular power spectrum";
set xlabel "scale (k)";
set ylabel "P(k)";
set key top left;
set grid;
set ytics out nomirror;
set xtics out nomirror;
set logscale x;
set format x "10^{%L}";
set yrange [0:30000];
plot "test_matterpower_$i.dat" u 1:2 w l > pic$i.jpeg;
EOFMarker
done

# Build movie with ffmpeg
ffmpeg -start_number 1 -i pic%d.jpeg  movie.mpeg
```

But I get the following output at execution :

```
 ./script_movie_gnuplot.sh
����JFIF``��;CREATOR: gd-jpeg v1.0 (using IJG JPEG v90), quality = 90
��C











��C
�����

���}!1AQa"q2��#B��R��$3br�
%&'()*456789:CDEFGHIJSTUVWXYZcdefghijstuvwxyz���������������������������������������������������������������������������

���w!1AQaq"2B����   #3R�br�
$4�%�&'()*56789:CDEFGHIJSTUVWXYZcdefghijstuvwxyz��������������������������������������������������������������������������
                                       ?�S��
(��
(��
(��
(��
(��
(��
(��
(��
(��
(��
(��
(��
(��
(��
(��
(��
(��
(��
(��
(��
(��
(��
(��
(��
(��
(��
(��1l�m��C�7����˟i�$�<7���lW���He� ��@���@������7�o�hb�?�}�~�?���/w˿��lu�2��N�i/ڤ�+}���7oT���l���s���(/ľ(Ѽ��k^!��t-���5;����

��*�����CĚN����R���N�m,~�p��fVu�,��ʣ�U�!X��4h��(h:����V�u+M_J�A-���<!���J���/�@P@P@o'�2��R`����S��  ���
(��
(��
(��
(��
(��
(��
(��
(��
(��
(��
(��
(��
(��>�.���|m�
            ~�����uY:e�i�Č��o"�<�n����������y�Y���jZm޵+�e��݅��JȬ��y�������f���ŏ�����n�ږ���-*+{��D�>���h�[��d$��@<��x�f�/e9Ϗ<@�Mu�yR���yp,e�ć웊˴�,��;ld;J�vw_����0�n�]w�iZ�垍�]+���f�ikt�2M��>Q��.#b��v��e�u�x���kq�;������!ӭ�.4�g�'��ip@�k+X+�T��5�#ž9�m�X��o�;wu'�<I��^j�}��m�k�[���+��s�@<oK�g�|y�W�W�m�[�#ƾ�o�{�CV�$��"�O�6�Mkp�ᤳh�Q*����P���㧏�k6�v��x��+}�_�S���5{��&�88�����0dpI��O�~)��ĝO��x�OӾ��*Ү������U]�UW��@�>�M�>&x���ޘ���/�_ͬE�E�����2��bB[�+���q@��V��oٓ�t����}i�-�3�i��
!2M0ayrTGN���K���w��~O�rx"�T��,��p����aP�%�9�m����~.j���?ٿ�Z���q�M
                                                                   ��徵wo��0���3F��Yܠ����+o��^�*ռc���m;ƶ��zj�����&�-�=�D��<@'r�e�@�Wŏ��'�o�uǪXx��H���zi��gkg��q
                                                                              YU�h|��2H��\m\�r�(�~"xGG�n�.��z�<a�.͜�t[]J�ԾЁc��g6�
~F��rgS�|g�|M]<A���5�r��S�߅�Y���4ׂ�c��+Y��]�V�h�Uv(��
                                                    ��+���~����oQ���G�u_
                                                                         ��q�h�c=����(IFݥ�a|�2k L�/�_���>-�͖�9Ӧ�V(~�z�����q�Ϸ!B/�@�v?��7�����'���O��f/
                                                                  x��v�n�gw
                                                                           ,������[���J&2�����6��S��4����.�mn�}���ޣ٘�\ǈ64��V
>m���y&�1�eg�����@��)�>"�q��|oc���2_i��G���{;;Ƕo����/���Sz�@<'·�<�4�~!��&��s��ˋ�
a2�[�>)�6��J�xQ�ƻ��xO�<˻kx��K�Ȥ��Q��(��܅��xǀ�.�O��2/I�7��|Q6��Z�oq"�]D���4h�J!���m Pxs� �l�Ri�A��.��s�;ޗH\�8��3�h�j(��
(��
(��
(��
(��
(��
(��
(��
(��
(��
(��
(��
N�T���?&h�ڛhDp�l|���j�_̠�P]c�L��c���_I�����i�2�-���n,B�G٣���N   ���u����U�ǌ<S�xI.!��X��1$3@���j�X�a1�\�A�A�
                        �-�����/�]�z6٭q]n�E��nw۾����d\
.��I#01�dq��TG%��q�}�O�z_��i�_YOw%��.mn�����Ak�P@)���$����n��|O�G����[��,�$[�F����HR(PUY��s6Y�y�ğ���_�!O���hz���v���E
                                  f��m�>h���\�?6� ����s�Ӿ��W�g�|I5���歫�a��=��`hg�����h��$of�O�g���⯊�]��_˥j�>{_�6��2�^l����
                                        A@Q��r�̓�@;�    ~�:?�<a�]x�ž$��u��z$:�ݻCko,>KDV(#���ܙ   Eː1@i?�W�|3��
�Þ&�7�5?i�h�~�a=�]�g+#I
                       �[w�Դh���AR(��#��VV�b���-��nbr�X�3��8߄�e����f��kZ���Oi"�L��˸g��̐�s�>\j]���ZJ��9w��d�
                        xz����x��¾����ȟLӮ�DɈ�α3K+�6����s�Q�?�|S�C^���k���:躴K2yQD!��.ϒVT�,Kd���
���l<'�-#E�����kM#�zu�?�
                        ��_2'�_4�����`@�    ��ٓºu���������u+��{�OR0�
                                                                       Ir�0T���@q��ҼG���mP�g�������t۩-nb
                     1�9c!��P�A�<'�o��q�xǷ��|B�σuo�G�h-����a�t�4�尣.ho���e�����ֿ�-WúH��4�n���s$+���m���JҰL�l�x�P�Ǉ�t+d�<Gy�=P���
{T�Ѽ_��h���u����v�s�3��Ă#s���X�Eb͑��W��\�����k��B<V�3�H[�H�!o$:�7d�),�B*��7�����x����X���{a�h/�����?������V1��T��㹸I�}"I/�|�X��BGݸ�@�~�^��.��6�Ն��x��]4�h��:���xy�ّ�?5z�P@P@P@P@P@P@��D��.�v��mzi"�l�De�Y�8��,�#�*���r�����7�#ӵ�/V�&��iˬ�i�$H�����^  e��)��R�`������|y�-#G���"���匚��6�i1��鴻òWe`��c�G&����
v�]/F�]լK��wI��q0�ʻ��6<��I��f����Ԟ�5�J�M#^���^�����-b:U��2'�#D�+Ȉ�,M1�:�pc������{]����Gs�L�!Y&�dԴ�F�Xӭo�g����$� �m�$l+) ��@h��
(��
(��
(��
(��
(��
(��
(��
(��
(��
(��
(��
(��
(��
(��
(��
(��
(��
(��ߏt�~�%�^���5���eX���;W{�.p�X�    ��><xkT����;��7�5o|)������{�(E#-��~B�k
                                                                              �4쩳{4lK8<zW�=oO���o�������[��R���:<��+m�f��2�㨠CԬ����c�Ɲ4_<5bt�a�.t�{��9%���G��_^[�~ÿs4M���>������경�U�ŤI�u�9
�=�Z_��G��z����wK���R3XI�[E�<��M��)^�쿳>���k�r�[�����c�}2��A�k�6{�(>1|g��9�j�����x���V�.��k$�o�mJ�*����VeH�a#`C  9��.O�  �������<]�D'��x{������w�������Z��
                                                                          ����B~ �w���k@�.O�    �������<]�D'��x{������w�������Z��
                                                  ����B~ �w���k@�.O�    ������G����$�{#��$U�<:J6��o�pp�p{{���<]�D'��x{������w�������Z��
                                                      ����B~ �w���k@�.O�    �������<]�D'��x{������w�������Z��
                               ����B~ �w���k@�.O�   ������F�R�  ���;�:�u�eR?��@,�=�Z��'����@����ր�\�.�����=��Z?�rx���O�����-h������!??�;����'����@����ր�\�.�����=��Z?�rx���O�����-h������!??�;������T7��ą�I�xuAf`�9պ�@� P��<]�D'��x{������w�������Z��
       ����B~ �w���k@�.O�   �������<]�D'��x{������w�������Z��
                                                                  ����B~ �w���k@�.O�    �������<]�D'��x{���St�����P3!h��
                                     �U��PAv ���'����@����ր�\�.�����=��Z?�rx���O�����-h������!??�;����'����@����ր�\�.�����=��Z?�rx���O�����-h������!??�;���
�����jY/�߈��g����S��\rc��P��\�.�����=��Z?�rx���O�����-h������!??�;����'����@����ր�\�.�����=��Z?�rx���O�����-h������!??�;����'����@����ր+�|s�>�
�s�7�q����|>r�:�5^��?h��.O� �������<]�D'��x{������w�������Z��
                                                                  ����B~ �w���k@�.O�    �������<]�D'��x{������w�������Z��
                                       ����B~ �w���k@�%��_��5���(�^�{�]궒�r��<V��E2�iy9
     ��
�#��B�Þ�t{eo�Y�iwoլ�c�  �:H�`�)�8 �7�~xW�՜�~�Ώ�I��e�F���9�̱��}�3��
?᷄t��x����-��o�γo�����0]�8Oj.�F���x����-Ǌ-�$:ܺ|-{�Y��`<G���>0���W^�kn���t�n&�9�bwR�s��Ett�_�����O�5��!��=V�
(��
~.�?V��čǳM����Ş�s�\�ڝ D)��b�I�X�$!ʳ6����We�������/��hK��c�:Z%�0�d���kr�[͇(���$*
�8�N���V��v:Uռ�#�m|��S�l�m�9�[~��H�n#,��]��(w�/����                           .@
                             �r.��n�>�B�p�� �|�����5����OØ��0^k���i����퍼^C���3"��C��Z���x���:�,�?��VM"���^Q�$W�A0[��j4��
                          w�x�K�-�S
1U��&�ܣ�<z��w�
              ��v�+�<>��I:���4���\�2�sf3���|O�Dk������<[c���߼�Wlgh�mf��L�C�+�
                                                                              �9��?�ޡ��.��xG�V�^ғL��ķz����O��&��@ŝD�Y���$�Pg���u������~��|��t{][�en�-'��E�!1o$ʈ$n9Fh�t��?k+�/��>}C�g��)��C�#T   z�o1������"X#�d��ȍ��� �&��V�
                                                            ~�A�߅$���SCU��Z��+��W��6�<�v��]��6<o�WE�߈w��<2�%�
                          �f���������{���B"�Vg��8�@Bq�
                                                      �~��|��^�1_x2}%n�=a�  ���@����jZs�G�еb��O�Z�%P~R%hb$��                              �ր*�D>->�O��� $�#��[i��+�`��\����,��<��*ֵ�~Κ��˯��z�Z��>e��V��d�P��Pp��(�������'��7�~�X��n�=������;�.���+e���9"v-$X'
Y�(-7㞹�|/�sk�e��/�t�kP��5���SAv���]F��ѵ����?�o��)x��q�|eio�/��6�ey�4N�E%F���Y8w��V�>X��w���/�M�׼I���hr[k&�>�q:)�U7rlq�tv�����E��@ݷ���uԾfm���|A���� �|��m�>�۹ߌ
                                                                             d�~(����_����3��A��_h��*�H~���|��tc8��%��,~�پ.֬���׃u;�/�z;�m�X��wly�
                                                             ��;B�  U�Y���a�x�����k]^^Ov��k:\������^8�3��yW
                             ��[��{�
                                    ��>"�G�u�w�>��3ް�ީ>��=��#K���V���v�v�6wr�M�Z�HbH��9X�(,�Y��$�ܒhJ(��
(��3�ݯ�[��k�c��nyG���������P�P@P@����,��}�7V��W��tȾ^;o���û=�B�
(��
(�*��?���<K���z�P@P@P@�_�����O�5��!��=V�
(��
(��>5�'��:��V��ۛ9]�3,L�����Z�u�h    �={�>�O�|�������F�jR%Y�i-Y��L
���$��>b��g������F��/���}f]CS�h�c�}��$v�K
                                         gM���x$g���r6���|)�:S�gG���՟�l<)��hzl0"��Epa.��$��C>`s@��e�P†_�_VR�z��l����2?
��?�ڟ�|5�E��zև�i�t�O^�t�A��d�Y%tB63����2��PK{�[\����^MF����~��+��G�G�r,�rB6`��BK<����xk�C���������|�M;Y���.��Ao)/$�ۏ*VV/6�rh�ֿf��7��'��4tv�����O��Z\�';eC.쌢�
�;�n� x��:g��x��b�ݛ����B��
                          ����0�-d3C�-��=/���c�~<�k�:�L�[�[%�
                                                               i�[�H�Q�P�`�|�H�:�>�������[E�n|?o�-6{q��f���n<�{F��#�    =҉X��)9��5�B�Ή�i����m�-B�Q��,�U��on{�T��m�̩)�p��@6<a�)K���
Iud>ϡ�mGDb�yu����e��%�Il�#�=@�h�μ>
x[O�]ׅ�c�
        F�����6�u��ʖ��-��>�?��$�� ?�>�{������j^ ԴI�to
                                                     i���Y���Cs'�w�S\� �U;�˱�|t�m��W]+ş�+�Q�YŎ��[ZNc$��$um���J��o�^�ף��3���M��t4-R
                                                ߳�ݳ������3�㡠C�ÿ����Z�-��y--���i�n.cV��wLG2�DM�
            �h����U�ŋ�מ����y5ˋ����d�KY��#��ºEf�kg���0��f?�o�>נ�|�K�?��g���2ϳE��V\Y�o'�����,|���@�/�~xs�j���:߀���|˙�༵�ys4L!b%Uto(��w/�
                                                  @>���Ï�|q�����G����~���X<��'��6ٜ�ٛ�~��c����_Zjz���>��p�c%̲��#�F89#�-��MR���~ ��F����o�漵�X.ݻ�����|O�➭����~��Z7�$���=��$
  lvn��
       S�`
�Z8Y.����\��������34���U�
                         �=_P��S�����Hn"h]��xd
��RD!��ᔂ �WNn���k�}Rk��^MY�*2p�������q�|;�A��i��U{�����i���[�a�����!�
Gÿ������%Q��Z�&�� �5���.��"�|;�A��i��U�����i��[�a�����!�
Gÿ������%Q��Z�&�� �5���.��"�|;�A��i��U�����i��[�a�����'^!�P@�\���-�ٿ˵�O��X�<����~�m����B�
(��
(�
  �r��Q��>Û�x��+�ݺd_/��f��ݞ��@P@P�x��N����%���
�=V�
(��
(��
(��
����Mc�'�����@�@P@P@�eϟ{�'�>���,~W���������wo��M1�4�@P@P|�;u�;�l�-g��~V|ݯ�7�ٻ��Р�
(��
(?\��%�o�ϰ���?7��7n���m�ٻ�wg�hP@P@P~�s�)�n���~o����3����1�w�m�zР�
(��
(>
  �����7�v�I�?+V�y���ۍ����hP@P@��\��7�g�suo��y��L�������;�ڀ4(��
(��
�����<��3Ŀ�]�P��@P@P@P@U�X�ɬ|d��3Y����h��
(��
(?L���ud�gڼ�����}��17�������?��4(��
(��
Ϟ�n�go�͞e��}��ϛ��f��7co3?�@P@P@g�?d������[���^f��"�x�;7��
(��
(��
���~�e#��غ���fu���f6n�-��@P@P@g�s�_���f�.�    >��c���3}�q�����
(��
(��3�˟�YF�l�n���|�3v�|�vߝ���v{P�P@P@U�?�:���&x��K�*�Z(��
(��
(��
(ʿk�5����&k?�C5z�P@P@g�>}l�W�t��^Vϳ��&���yݿw�4����P@P@�������ٳ̵�O��Y�v�C���f�m��g�hB�
(��
(�
  �r��Q��>Û�x��+�ݺd_/��f��ݞ��@P@P@�����}�W�W��lξ^;����ŷ=�B�
(��
(�
  �.wk��l����'��y[�Q�o�n6����T�@P@P~�s�K(��a�ռ~o��n�2/����w���jР�
(��
(ʼG�'O�������v�@�@P@P@P@yW�c�&�����g�Hf�U��
(��
(�
  �2�ϽՓ�j�n�?+������^�;������Р�
(��
hP@P@��\��7�g�suo��y��L�������;�ڀ4(��
(��
(?C��]���Ϸb��?7�������}�ٻ��hP@P@���~����X$���+s�<�������^��4(��
(��
��.~�e��9������ۦE���~vn���@P@P@yW�����ؙ�_�.Ш�h��
(��9����o�~��.�$ɧژ��m�i��E�(�A�;��=Xt�@ǅ>=iZ��΅��'_Ӵ���|C�
                                                          U�#{y���[
�~�,��dP_
>7�|Z�еK_�~/�|;�Y&�i���B
                        ��"-7�N�Ԯ� ��o8����I�k�5�ZF�i�k���z7��b]/S�M�����U��ɱ�M�#6Fg��Ɖ�jV�i����T��/�kҬoY�<��%!^DF�bhюԃ�
�i�h�ȥէ�";��d)                       ?�/�����/'�mc��
��0�@# ���6�Ɲkc<wVWQ$�OnI#`YOpAz�?���Mc�'�����@�@P@P@�eϟ{�'�>���,~W���������wo��M1�4�@P@P|�;u�;�l�-g��~V|ݯ�7�ٻ��Р�
(��
(?\��%�o�ϰ���?7��7n���m�ٻ�wg�hP@P@P~�s�)�n���~o����3����1�w�m�zР�
(��
(>
  �����7�v�I�?+V�y���ۍ����hP@P@��\��7�g�suo��y��L�������;�ڀ4(��
(��
�����<��3Ŀ�]�P��@P@ax���    �^%�&�����y�R�K31
�,�  P�7����O��Σ��;Q�ރa�YFd��47Y�Q$��VB��#"a�j�L��m㿃^�W�o�_����K�;Q�%ԭ�N�Of��5v+m�U��F��������Yk�/���:h��#Oxj�����\���r
                                      Ko9|�;�
� ����~7x:�h����}{F6��'���e{0��H����*r8�z�������]��
                                                   {[��Y���
v�����������gg��uo5f��s�����)6T{����o?������������������ӹ��M��z��~��<?�}�����w?�    ���_?������Ͽ��?۠�N���7������~����Y�����ti���&��=|������>����n��;���ǯ��������g������s�@�������?�x����s�?���y��߇�������@���o?�����������������?L�.g�Փ췗^N�<�����ɉ�˟3�s�~���o�hC�N���7������~����Y�����ti���&��=|������>����n��;���ǯ��������g������s�@�������?�x����s�?���y��߇�������@���o?������������������ӹ��M��z��~��<?�}�����w?�   ���_?������Ͽ��?۠
                       ��˕�����x�f�=����|�W�l��p����4?���y��߇�������@���o?������������������ӹ��M��z��~��<?�}�����w?�   ���_?������Ͽ��?۠�N���7������~����Y�����ti���&��=|������>����n��;���ǯ��������g������s�@�������?�x����s���5˛K(�췖9�<�n�d��2/�q�p�����(C�N���7������~����Y�����ti���&��=|������>����n��;���ǯ��������g������s�@�������?�x����s�?���y��߇�������@���o?������������������ӹ��M��z��~��<?�}�����w?�  ���_?������Ͽ��?۠�N���7������~����Y�����t���7vR?�o/��<ݰǵ�g_�����}�۝������o?������������������ӹ��M��z��~��<?�}�����w?�    ���_?������Ͽ��?۠�N���7������~����Y�����ti���&��=|������>����n��;���ǯ��������g������s�@�������?�x����s�?���y��߇�������@�k�-��[���2
          ���yN�(ٿ���n1����5hi���&��=|������>����n��;���ǯ��������g������s�@�������?�x����s�?���y��߇�������@���o?������������������ӹ��M��z��~��<?�}�����w?�  ���_?������Ͽ��?۠�N���7������~����Y�����t��k�6�Q��o,s�y<ݰɹ�d_�����;7}�ݝ�P����o?������������������ӹ��M��z��~��<?�}�����w?�    ���_?������Ͽ��?۠�N���7������~����Y�����ti���&��=|������>����n��;���ǯ��������g������s�@�������?�x����s�?���y��߇�������@e���q�S�;�-&�ρ�G!�J3_hyO��̸��
                           �=v�
(��
(��
M���M"GY�W���e9Rc�J� ���g��5Iu? |?��)aki/4]��g��cx�IRUI\�*=hxS��|}}{�   h^��9���t�md�9��5������>+��E���[/�)[�f�O�;���`��p:��]|6���]υ�[�[�Hu�t�Z�5�0���8�4x�᷄|a��ڮ��m[�4��c{����Mjs��矔���ʿk�5����&k?�C5z�P@P@g�>}l�W�t��^Vϳ��&���yݿw�4����P@P@�������ٳ̵�O��Y�v�C���f�m��g�hB�
(��
(�
  �r��Q��>Û�x��+�ݺd_/��f��ݞ��@P@P@�����}�W�W��lξ^;����ŷ=�B�
(��
(�
  �.wk��l����'��y[�Q�o�n6����T�@P@P~�s�K(��a�ռ~o��n�2/����w���jР�
(��
(ʼG�'O�������v�@�@P@P@P@yW�c�&�����g�Hf�U��
(��
(�
  �2�ϽՓ�j�n�?+������^�;������Р�
(��
hP@P@��\��7�g�suo��y��L�������;�ڀ4(��
(��
(?C��]���Ϸb��?7�������}�ٻ��hP@P@���~����X$���+s�<�������^��4(��
(��
��.~�e��9������ۦE���~vn���@P@P@yW�����ؙ�_�.Ш�h��
(��
(��
(�*���>2ؙ���
             ��P@P@��\��}��^M���y[>������v�����@P@P@g�s�_���f�2�y>��g���3m�������
(��
(��3�˟�YF�l�n���|�3v�|�vߝ���v{P�P@P@g�w?k������]\G��^^ݳ:�x���
(��
(��3�ݯ�[��k�c��nyG���������P�P@P@����,��}�7V��W��tȾ^;o���û=�B�
(��
(�*��?���<K���z�P@P@P@�_�����O�5��!��=V�
(��
...
```

Where is my error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do:

```
plot "test_matterpower_$i.dat" u 1:2 w l > pic$i.jpeg;
```

You need to set the output:

```
set output "pic$i.jpeg";
plot "test_matterpower_$i.dat" u 1:2 w l;
```